# How to choose the size of the Design Tab in Java (Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm working on Java with Swing and I chose a 600x400 size for my frame. I'd like however to add `JButtons` or `JLabels` in an area not visible in the window in its default size but only if resized up to the fullscreen dimension. To do so I need to work in the Design Tab with a bigger size frame (with respect to my desired default size), but of course it appears of the same size of the output frame.

Is there a way to work with a full screen design tab but still having a running default window's size of 600x400? Or to work in the design tab on areas not visible in the chosen portion of the frame ?